# Открыть файл, который находится внутри проекта - Java SE

Tags: java, uri, project

Пробую вот так:

```
String dir = new File(getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath()).getParent();
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("DshifrHelp.chm");
assert url != null;
File file = new File(url.toURI());
manualItem.setOnAction(e -> {
    try {
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

но при сборке JAR получаю:

> uri is not hierarchical

Читала про `InputStream`, но не поняла, как переделать его в `Desktop.getDesktop().open(htmlFile);`.

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте не просто копировать код , а разбираться в том, что вы, собственно , пишите.

```
File file = new File("DshifrHelp.chm");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

разумеется, третья строка кидает исключение. разумеется, "DshifrHelp.chm" - относительный путь, т.е. файл с указанным именем лежит в корне вашего проекта. можете добавить условие с проверкой типа file.еxist , чтобы быть уверенным , что такой файл найден

Comment: Я получаю урл файла, который лежит в папке с ресурсами потом его открываю. Почему относительной путь? Он разве не в ресурсы смотрит?

Comment: вы понимаете, что такое вырвать гланды через.... ну, не важно. ваша задача решается в одну строчку. зачем вы изобретаете велосипед?

Comment: Как? Про гланды жопу и костыли понимаю, но скилл пока не позволяет лучше

Comment: я же вам написал как. в файл вы передаете путь к файлу. можно как относительный, так и абсолютный. и все будет работать.

Comment: Хм, мне кажется я так пробовала, но не работало. Попробую ещё раз, если заработает будет хорошо)

Comment: ну, давайте иначе... Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("DshifrHelp.chm")); в кавычках, где написано ваше имя файла, вы имеете обычный стринг. т.е. вы можете , используя переменную, передать туда любой путь с именем файла и его открыть. что вам еще надо? разумеется, использовать абсолютный путь глупо. а относительный, например, вгылядит так: src/resource/DshifrHelp.chm

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы файл открывался именно из папки с ресурсами. С подгрузкой картинок почему-то проблем не возникло, а с файлом, который нужно именно открыть не получается. Как использовать относительной путь в джар ?

Comment: в общем, если не получится , пишите, будем разбираться...

Comment: какая у вас система сборки?

Comment: Maven, но пробовала и обычный билд

Comment: так, а вы понимаете, что jar - по сути обічный зип-архив со всеми вытекающими? хорошо, попробуйте скомпилировать свой джарник, а рядом с ним в той же папке положить свой DshifrHelp.chm, при этом в коде напишите так Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("DshifrHelp.chm"));

Comment: Понимаю) так не интересно, хочу чтобы из ресурсов тянул. Просто мне кажется очень странным, что нет простого способа открыть файл лежащий в самом проекте

Comment: Нет, если вы хотите читать файл из джарника, то это делается через ресурсы по указанной мной причине. Джар - это зип-архив, соотвественно, передать имя и путь файла просто класу файл не выйдет. Но для начала хотя бы прочитайте файл так,как я написал, а уже потом пойдем дальше

Comment: да, если положить рядом с джарником, то работает.

Comment: в общем сделала через WebView. Отдельная вьюха и открытие файла внутри приложения